# I am trying to write a web scraping crawler to try and scrape a website but I always get the error "ReactorNotRestartable"

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, anaconda

Here's the full code that I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
import scrapy 
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class quote_collector(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "quote_collector_spider"

  def start_requests( self ):
    main_url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?'
    urls = [ 'https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?' ]
    for i in range(98):
        url = main_url+'page='+str(i+2)
        urls.append(url)

    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request( url = url, callback = self.parse )

  def parse( self, response ):

    quote_blocks = response.xpath('//div[@class="quoteText"]')

    my_quotes = []

    for block in quote_blocks:
        quote = block.xpath('text()').extract_first().strip()
        author = block.xpath('.//span[@class="authorOrTitle"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
        ref = block.xpath('.//span/a[@class="authorOrTitle"]/text()').extract_first()

        my_quotes.append([quote, author, ref])

    quotes_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Quote','Author','Referrence'])
    quotes_df = pd.concat(quotes_df, pd.DataFrame(my_quotes, columns = ['Quote','Author','Referrence']))

# initiate a CrawlerProcess
process = CrawlerProcess()
# tell the process which spider to use
process.crawl(quote_collector)
# start the crawling process
process.start()
```

And the error that I get is here:

*
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 309, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1282, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1262, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 765, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()

ReactorNotRestartable
*
Please help me understand what's this error and what is it that I am doing wrong here.

Comment: The error is about your scrapy installation not the code.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am using Anaconda -> Spyder, shall I uninstall and reinstall it? Would that solve the issue?

Comment: I don’t get that exception when I run your code, the spider “works” (with TypeErrors everywhere). Either your code is different, or you are calling it in a way different from `python script.py`.

Comment: Ok. I am going to reinstall the anaconda and try it again. Thanks.